# Passing key-values to another array with different length

Tags: javascript

Hi I have two arrays with objects inside it. I'm trying to pass the hash value of the title attribute to the other array's object that has the title key-value pair too but doesn't have the hash (it's an empty string).

The trick is that the arrays are unsorted and they have different lengths.

This is my code:

```js
var res = [
  [{
      title: "time goes by",
      searchhash: ""
    },
    {
      title: "gta vice city",
      searchhash: ""
    },
    {
      title: "miami beach",
      searchhash: ""
    }
  ],

  [{
      title: "miami beach",
      search_hash: "12456"
    },
    {
      title: "time goes by",
      search_hash: "98765"
    }
  ]

]

for (var i = 0; i < res[0].length; i++) {
  if (res[0][i].searchhash === "") {
    titlePass(res[0][i].title)
    res[0][i].searchhash = function hashPass(p) {
      console.log(p);
      i += 1
    }
  }
}

function titlePass(t) {
  //Here I'm getting the titles (t)
  res[1].forEach((obj) => {
    if (t === obj.title) {
      hashPass(obj["search_hash"])
    }
  })
}
```

But I get hashPass is not a function. I know that I can access those values of the hashPass function outisde the for loop, but I want to get those values being passed inside the for loop to assign it to the searchhash property...

Comment: you haven't shown your hashPass function - have you created one?

Comment: You will run into many issues trying to do it this way, like, a ton. Dont define functions within loops, use forEach to loop through arrays instead, use Object.keys to loop through objects. Can write you an example if you want, but you will need to figgure out how to implement it with your own data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try following code.

```
var res = [
  [{
      title: "time goes by",
      searchhash: ""
    },
    {
      title: "gta vice city",
      searchhash: ""
    },
    {
      title: "miami beach",
      searchhash: ""
    }
  ],

  [{
      title: "miami beach",
      search_hash: "12456"
    },
    {
      title: "time goes by",
      search_hash: "98765"
    }
  ]

]

for (var i = 0; i < res[0].length; i++) {
  if (res[0][i].searchhash === "") {
    titlePass(res[0][i]);
  }
}

function titlePass(o) {
  res[1].forEach((obj) => {
    if (o.title === obj.title) {
      o["searchhash"] = obj["search_hash"];
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?

```js
var res = [
  [{
      title: "time goes by",
      searchhash: ""
    },
    {
      title: "gta vice city",
      searchhash: ""
    },
    {
      title: "miami beach",
      searchhash: ""
    }
  ],

  [{
      title: "miami beach",
      search_hash: "12456"
    },
    {
      title: "time goes by",
      search_hash: "98765"
    }
  ]

]


for (var i = 0; i < res[0].length; i++) {
  var res0 = res[0][i];
  if (res0.searchhash === "") {
    var title = res0.title;
    for (var j=0;j<res[1].length;j++) {
      var res1 = res[1][j];
      if (res1.title == title) res0.searchhash=res1.search_hash;
    }
  }
}
console.log(res)
```